# Facebook API get shared friends likes with same app installed

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I need to get in some way the shared likes between friends using the same app, some FQL that finally return to me a list of most common likes, is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: I can get the users that have the same app installed, so I will need how to join this list user to get the shared likes: SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND is_app_user = 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a look at this, and to get the likes for a current user based off the indexable user_id field, you need a user_access token for the current user.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/

What this basically means is,only the current user of your app at a particular time can query information based on their likes. Something like the following query might work for you. Be aware that you need the read_stream permission

```
select object_id, user_id,object_type FROM like WHERE object_id in(SELECT object_id FROM like WHERE user_id =me()) and user_id in(select uid FROM user WHERE uid in(SELECT uid2 FROM friend where uid1 = me()) and is_app_user='true')
```

you can try this out at

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/433871385166/?fql=select%20object_id%2C%20user_id%2Cobject_type%20FROM%20like%20WHERE%20object_id%20in(SELECT%20object_id%20FROM%20like%20WHERE%20user_id%20%3Dme())%20and%20user_id%20in(select%20uid%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%20in(SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20where%20uid1%20%3D%20me())%20and%20is_app_user%3D'true')
```

You would then most likely need to use some server side code to analyse the returned data to count what is most popular. Possibly by creating an array, looping through the data, check if there is a key in the array based off the object_id, if there isn't add that key to the array with a value of 1 (where 1 is the count) otherwise increase the value by 1.

pseudo code example

```
  $data; // This would be what was returned from your FQL query
  $compare = array();
  foreach($data as $value){
    if(array_key_exists($value['object_id'],$compare)){
       $compare['object_id'] = $value['object_id'] + 1;
    }else{
       $compare['object_id'] = 1;
    }
  }
  // Do some sorting function to compare the counts.
  //you would then probably need to batch queries to get the name/title of the object that the user has liked
```

I hope this gives you a good starting point